# Activate certain form elements based on value of checkbox in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a following code in jQuery Mobile

```
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
            <legend>Is this move permanent or temporary?</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="moveinfo" value="p" id="movetype_0" class="defhide required" checked="checked">
                <label for="movetype_0" id="permanentlabel">Permanent</label>
                <input type="radio" name="moveinfo" value="t" id="movetype_1" class="toggleCheck required ">
                <label for="movetype_1" id="temporarylabel">Temporary</label>
        </fieldset>
```

If temporary is checked, (Touch Event), as new form control with id "stopdatediv" should be activated that is preveously hided using display none property.

```
  <div id="stopdatediv" style="display:none">  
                <label for="stopdate" >Stop forwarding on</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" id="stopdate" value="" class="required" data-role="datebox"
   data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'>
                </div>
```

I am trying to bind events, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
jQuery(document).bind("pageinit", function (){
  jQuery("#movetype_1").on("tap", function(){
              jQuery("#stopdatediv").show();
  });
});
```

I tried, tap, click etc.

How to display the stopdatediv.

Comment: We have loads of similar questions well responded here. Please use the search feature to save your time waiting for the answer.

Comment: Regret for the inconvenience, I actually thought the question have something to do with Touch events that is not responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery("#movetype_1").on("change", function(){
              if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                  jQuery("#stopdatediv").show();
  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzTP4/)

Comment: Worked !!!. Yes, checkboxes work in different way i forgot. I thought mobile events didn't work.